# Howl of Fury provoking opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

Curious if a barbarian's Howl of Fury provokes opportunity attacks, as it does not specify *CLOSE* blast. I think it's reasonable to assume it does not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, Howl of Fury does not provoke OAs.**

From Primal Power, p11 (emphasis mine):

> **Howl of Fury**
>   ...
>   *Melee weapon*
>   ...
>   Hit: 1[W] + Strength modifier damage. You then howl in a blast 3 that includes the target. Each enemy in the blast, other than the target, takes thunder damage equal to your Constitution modifier. ...

You provoke OAs by making ranged or area attacks (not melee or close attacks). Howl of Fury is a melee attack (it happens to affect a blast, but it's still a melee attack). Therefore Howl of Fury does not provoke OAs.

Comment: You're the best Oblivious Sage